# Find object in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Imagine I've got an array of objects like so (dummy code):

```
const chosenBets = [{...}, {...}] // 2 items
```

And I want to delete a specific item from the array:

```
{id: 0, // is unique
 label: 1,
 odd: 1.33,
 oddIndex: 0,
 team_home: "Liverpool",
 team_away: "Sheffield United",
 matchCardIndex: 0,}
```

So that array is now:

```
const chosenBets = [{...}] // 1 items
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use array `filter`

```js
const chosenBets = [{
  id: 0, // is unique
  label: 1,
  odd: 1.33,
  oddIndex: 0,
  team_home: "Liverpool",
  team_away: "Sheffield United",
  matchCardIndex: 0
}, {
  id: 1, // is unique
  label: 1,
  odd: 1.33,
  oddIndex: 0,
  team_home: "Liverpool",
  team_away: "Sheffield United",
  matchCardIndex: 0
}];

const filteredData = chosenBets.filter(item => item.id === 1);
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice`

```js
var a = [{
    id: 0, // is unique
    label: 1,
    odd: 1.33,
    oddIndex: 0,
    team_home: "Liverpool",
    team_away: "Sheffield United",
    matchCardIndex: 0,
  },
  {
    id: 0, // is unique
    label: 11,
    odd: 1.33,
    oddIndex: 0,
    team_home: "Liverpool",
    team_away: "Sheffield United",
    matchCardIndex: 0,
  }
]
a.forEach((e, j) => {
  if (e.label == 1)
    a.splice(j, 1);
})
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a specific and unique object, I would do something like:

```
let chosenBets = [{
  id: 0, // is unique
  label: 1,
  odd: 1.33,
  oddIndex: 0,
  team_home: "Liverpool",
  team_away: "Sheffield United",
  matchCardIndex: 0
}, {
  id: 1, // is unique
  label: 1,
  odd: 1.33,
  oddIndex: 0,
  team_home: "Liverpool",
  team_away: "Sheffield United",
  matchCardIndex: 0
}];

let index = chosenBets.findIndex(({id}) => id === 1);

// if you want to mutate the original array, otherwise use `slice`
chosenBets.splice(index, 1);
console.log(chosenBets);
```

`filter` is better if you want to remove a group of elements, not just one. The reason is, it keeps going to iterate all the elements of the array, so it *always* iterate the whole array, even if the element you want to remove is the first one.
Using `findIndex` you just iterate until you find the element, and then return the index: so as average, it does less cycle.